# C++ Memory Leak Passing a string to C# code

Tags: c#, c++, memory-leaks

We have a c# application which receives data from a c++ project using a callback method:

```
/* c# code */
call[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private unsafe delegate void NewFrame(string serial, Int32* width, Int32* height, short* frame);
```

In our C++ project (which receives data from a camera), we call this 'NewFrame' callback method very frequently, passing camera frames to the c# code.

The definition of this method in c++ is:

```
/* c++ code */
typedef void (__stdcall * NewFrame)(char* serialnumber, INT32* width,INT32* height, int16_t* frame);
```

To pass the 'serial', whe convert a c++ string object to a char* in the c++ code:

```
/* c++ code */
char* stringToCsharpString(string s){
    char* cserial = new char[s.length() + 1];
    strcpy(cserial, s.c_str());
    return cserial;
}
```

However, this causes a (heap) memory leak, as the cserial object is not released.

This is how this NewFrame method is called in c++:

```
/* c++ code */
newFrame(stringToCsharpString(node.getSerialNumber()), &w, &h, data.frame);
```

What can we do to fix this? We are proficient in c#, but not at all in c++. So when talking about c++ code, please explain thoroughly :)

Comment: you need to delete this dynamic memory in the Dispose() method of the c# wrapper object

Comment: it also depends on what NewFrame is doing with the string. If access is readonly and synchronous, and the pointer is not stored anywhere (i.e. the caller waits for completion and `NewFrame()` copies and/or transforms the data somehow), you can just use  `s.c_str()` proper as the argument.

Comment: In any event, you shouldn't be passing classes such as `std::string` across module boundaries.  C# knows nothing about `std::string`, it's internal implementation, etc.  That parameter to `NewFrame` should simply be a pointer to a character buffer (array) that C# created, no more, no less.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Just to avoid misunderstandings -- you really mean that the argument should be a buffer that C# created (not C++ which is the caller here, where the data originates)? If we assume using a buffer created at the C++ side for a moment: `s.c_string()` would fit the bill of "simply being a pointer to a character buffer", so it wouldn't be prohibited by your (sensible) caveat of not passing C++ `std::string`s. Do we agree?

Comment: @RonaldoMessi How would I be deleting this memory? All I get in C# is a string object

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: that is wat I am doing, but it has a memory leak...

Comment: @Fortega -- There is a defacto method of marshaling string data between C# and C++.  That method boils down to C# owning the buffer, and just passing the buffer to C++.  The C++ code can do whatever it wants internally inside the function that is being called (for example, convert the passed-in buffer into a `std::string` for ease of use) but at the end of the day, the C# code doesn't care or interact at all with the "internal" `std::string` object (if there is one used) within the C++ code.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert C++ unmanaged memory into managed memory in C#, you can use *gcnew* :

```
String^ ConvertUnmanagedString2ManagedString(char* cserial)
{
     return gcnew String(cserial)
}
```

Here, I'm assuming that your cserial content encoding is UCS-2 ofcourse. I don't know what is the content of cserial but if it is encoded in UTF8 or some other encoding other than UCS-2, you also need to apply a text encoding transformation because C# String encoding is UCS-2.